# Counting positive smiles in string using R

Tags: r, string

In src$Review each row is filled with text in Russian. I want to count the number of positive smiles in each row. For example, in "My apricot is orange)) (for sure)" I want to count not just the quantity of outbound brackets (i.e., excluding general brackets in "(for sure)"), but the amount of positive smiling characters ("))" — at least two outbound brackets, number of ":)", ":-)"). So, it works only if at least two outbound brackets are exhibited.

Assume there is a string "I love this girl!)))) (she makes me happy) every day:):) :-)!" Here we count: )))) (4 units), ":)" (2 units), ":-)" (1 unit). After we combine the number of units (i.e., 7). Pay attention that we don't count brackets in "(she makes me happy)".

Now I have following code in my script:

```
smilecounts <- str_count(src$Review, "[))]")
```

It counts only the total amount of bracket pairs ("()") (as I understand comparing data set and derivation of this command). 
I only need the total amount of ":)", ":-)", "))" (the total number of outbound brackets which display as "))" in rows) to be counted. For example, in ")))))" appear 5 outbound brackets, the condition of at least two outbound brackets together is satisfied, than we count the total amount of brackets in this part of text (i.e., 5 outbound brackets).

Thank you so much for help in advance.

Comment: Please provide some example strings and your *exact* desired output.

Comment: Assume there is a string "I love this girl!)))) (she makes me happy) every day:):) :-)!" Here we count: )))) (4 units), ":)" (2 units), ":-)" (1 unit). After we combine the number of units (i.e., 7). Pay attention that we don't count brackets in "(she makes me happy)".

Comment: Please edit the question it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds to extract the `)` that follows a `)` or `:` or `:=`, then use `length` to get the count.

```
length(str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=\\)|\\!)\\)')[[1]])
#[1] 4

length(str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=:)\\)')[[1]])
#[1] 2

length(str_extract_all(str1, '(?<=:-)\\)')[[1]])
#[1] 1
```

Or this can be done using a loop

```
pat <- c('(?<=\\)|\\!)\\)', '(?<=:)\\)', '(?<=:-)\\)')
sum(sapply(lapply(pat, str_extract_all, string=str1),
     function(x) length(unlist(x))))
#[1] 7
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "I love this girl!)))) (she makes me happy) every day:):) :-)!"
```

Comment: @RuslanSeletskiy  We can loop the patterns using `lapply` and then use `Reduce(`+`,..)` to get the sum of 7.  I am on a bus, so it is not easy to copy/paste without the mouse :-)

Comment: Try `pat <- c('(?<=\\)|\\!)\\)', '(?<=:)\\)', '(?<=:-)\\)'); sum(sapply(lapply(pat, str_extract_all, string=str1), function(x) length(unlist(x))))`

Comment: @RuslanSeletskiy  I am getting the exact result you showed using the example.  So, I don't know what you meant by doesn't work.

Comment: I mean that the code in the post above doesn't work. It shows "0L".

Comment: @RuslanSeletskiy  Sorry, I couldn't reproduce

Answer (score 1):

One way with `regexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
vec <- "I love this girl!)))) (she makes me happy) every day:):) :-)!"
```

Solution:

```
#matches the locations of :-) or ))+ or :)
a <- gregexpr(':-)+|))+|:)+', vec)
#extracts those
b <- regmatches(vec, a)[[1]]
b
#[1] "))))" ":)"   ":)"   ":-)" 
#table counts the instances
b
))))  :-)   :) 
   1    1    2
```

Then I suppose you could count the number of single `)`s using

```
nchar(b[1])
[1] 4
```

Or in a more automated way:

```
tab <- table(b)
#the following means "if a name of the table consists only of ) then 
#count the number of )s"
tab2 <- ifelse(gsub(')','', names(table(b)))=='', nchar(names(table(b))), table(b))
names(tab2) <- names(tab)

> tab2
))))  :-)   :) 
   4    1    2
```

Comment: I'm trying to come with it in this way 'smile counts <- str_count(src$Review, "|:-)+|))+|:)+|=)+")', but R says that this regular expression doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to use `str_count`? Doesnt the above give you what you need? Different functions work differently with regex. The `ifelse` above works fine along with table. Are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Yes, I need exactly using `str_count`.

Comment: This also doesn't work `smilecounts <- str_count(src$Review, c("\\)", "\\:)\\", "\\:-)\\", "\\=)\\"))`.

Comment: I have no experience in using `str_count`. You should also mention in your question that you only want to use `str_count`.